# React - Child components not updating when setting the parent's state too quickly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, state, immutability

I have a big form with around 1000 dynamically rendered inputs (based on a database table) and each have their own reference in the parent's state array `inputs`. Here is the structure of said array :

```
[
  {
    descriptionEN: "",
    descriptionFR: ""
    feature: "PriceList"
    id: "PriceList_Cmb"
    label: "Price List"
    price: 0
    value: "2023-B"
  }
]
```

I have those 2 methods in the parent's component :

```
//Adds input to inputs state
addInput(newInput) {
    let inputsCopy = this.state.inputs;
    inputsCopy.push(newInput);
    this.setState({ inputs: inputsCopy });
}
//Updates input to new value
updateInput(id, updatedInput, setLastUpdated) {
    let inputsCopy = this.state.inputs;
    let inputIndex = inputsCopy.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
    inputsCopy[inputIndex] = updatedInput;

    if (setLastUpdated) {
        this.setState({ inputs: inputsCopy, lastUpdated: updatedInput });
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ inputs: inputsCopy });
    }
}
```

They work great when updating the child component (dropdown/select controls) manually, however, when updating them programmatically, they all call the updateInput method in the matter of 3-4 seconds (based on axios requests), and the parent component's state update does not trigger the componentDidUpdate on all child components.

It's a completely random behavior and I have been testing and searching for solutions for days, without success, even if the updateInput method is called, the application is not refreshed for some unknown reason, it only works if I do it slowly.

Tried to use all sorts of ways to set the array via other methods in both the addInput and updateInput method, used the spread operator to update the array's objects, without any success, the child components are not getting updates when the parent's inputs state gets updated, no matter the method to do so.

Comment: `let inputsCopy = this.state.inputs;` this doesn't create a copy. It should be `let inputsCopy = [...this.state.inputs];`

Comment: That's great advice regarding React's immutability, but I have tried to use this, the .map method, the react immutability-helper to recreate both my inputs and lastUpdated state to make sure React sees them as new objects, and for some reason my child component only sees certain updates, can I provide any more information to help figure this out? I put a console.log of the props directly in the componentDidUpdate method of the child, and it doesn't output all the changes that are being made. The inputs array gets updated properly, what I'm trying to catch are changes made to lastUpdated state

Comment: Maybe try to reproduce it on https://codesandbox.io/